# What level of TLS encryption is supported by the .NET Compact Framework 3.5

Tags: windows-mobile, ssl, compact-framework

I want to use an AES 256-bit web service with a Windows Mobile 6.1 application (.netcf 3.5).

I can't seem to find an answer ANYWHERE as to what types of encryption the SSL/TLS stack on the .net compact framework supports. Maybe I'm just being blind...

Please help! Going crazy!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one question for which the only correct answer is that "it depends".  In this case, it depends on the CryptoAPI provider(s) that were built into the OS image on the target device.

Comment: Do you know how I might go about researching this for a given device? The most pertinent of these being the Palm Treo Pro, but it would be nice to know what to look for in the future as we develop for other devices.

Comment: I believe it is dependent on the country of origin of the actual device.

Answer (score 0):

One method is to use a packet capture application like Wireshark to sniff the HTTPS session negotiation. In the initial TLS/SSL handshake, the client communicates with the server the ciphers it supports. You will be able to read the list from the packet capture.